# Serialize to parent type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class like:

```
public class DictionaryEx<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    public new TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            if(base.ContainsKey(key)) {
                return base[key];
            }
            return default(TValue);
        }
        set {
            if(value.Equals(default(TValue))) {
                if(base.ContainsKey(key)) {
                    base.Remove(key);
                }
            }
            else {
                base[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a `Dictionary` with different getter/setter semantics.

How can I get this to deserialize as either `Dictionary` or `DictionaryEx` depending on whether or not the app has the `DictionaryEx` type?

DLL sharing isn't an option. I can add code and attributes to this object but I can't(?) change the (de)serialization code. (De)serialization is likely to be done via MVC's session (de)serializer.

(I'm trying to get a `Dictionary` that behaves as described in the above code in my app but is a regular `Dictionary` in other apps.)

Comment: What does this class solve that the built-in Dictionary cannot solve ?

Comment: @ChesterCobus A dictionary with which I can use just the indexer without having to check for key existence or manually remove default values.

Comment: For the mentioned functionality and environment, [ViewDataDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505255) provides a `IDictionary<string, object>` that may be sufficient. It returns `null` values for non-existing keys and is available as part of the ASP.NET libraries (`System.Web.Mvc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about extension methods, I know it's not as fancy as overloading the [].

Will this help:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void SetValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (value == null && dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(key);
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return dictionary[key];
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd thought of this and was hoping to avoid it. This is likely to be the answer if nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have to do anything at all.  Since it doesn't look like you've added any new properties to your DictionaryEx class, wouldn't its (presumably JSON) serialized output be identical to a normal Dictionary's serialized output?  I believe this is the case, so any apps that DO have the DictionaryEx class should be able to deserialize it as DictionaryEx, and other apps should be able to deserialize the exact same JSON as a normal Dictionary, and everything should work fine in either situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the MVC session serializer is likely to use `BinaryFormatter` or some variant when using one of the external session stores.